# R: bench::mark does not return max and mean

Tags: r, benchmarking

Consider the follwoing example

```
res <- bench::mark(rnorm(1e5))
names(res)
#>  [1] "expression" "min"        "median"     "itr/sec"    "mem_alloc" 
#>  [6] "gc/sec"     "n_itr"      "n_gc"       "total_time" "result"    
#> [11] "memory"     "time"       "gc"
```

I am somewhat confused, that the mean and the maximum runtime are not included, contradicting the help page. Bench version is 1.0.4 and R 3.63.

Does anyone know what the issue is here?

Comment: The results are kept in `res$time[[1]]` and the mean and maximum values can be calculated from it. For instance, compare `median(res$time[[1]])` with the printed result.

Comment: If you write it as an answer I will accept it

Comment: Better option is to use `library(microbenchmark)` where the mean and maximum are calculated and can be stored into the variable.

Comment: I just realized that it is probably a good idea do not return the mean and the max, as they are probably influenced by windows calling some background processes and they therefore have no appropriate interpretation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is usually useful to run

```
str(res)
```

to see what is the output of functions. In this case one of the object's members, near the end, is

```
# $ time      :List of 1
#  ..$ : 'bench_time' num  12.3ms 16.1ms 17.9ms 12.3ms 13.4ms ...
```

This means that `res$time` is a list with just one member.
So the results are kept in `res$time[[1]]` and the mean and maximum values can be calculated from it.

For instance, compare `median(res$time[[1]])` with the printed result. They are the same value.

```
median(res$time[[1]])
#[1] 12.3ms
```

And the mean and maximum will be

```
mean(res$time[[1]])
#[1] 12.5ms
max(res$time[[1]])
#[1] 17.9ms
```